# How to work when internet connection down?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

How to work when internet connection down in a asp.net application ?
Means Users are working on application and suddenly internet connection down then user should still be able to add/edit/ delete operation on data, but when internet connection is up then 
all changes should be done at server. Is that possible, Is there any example available to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: HTML 5 has this option. Take a look **[here](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)**

Comment: Can you provide a little more information, e.g. your users are often collecting data in a tunnel and require that functionality? If so, maybe a Silverlight app with a "sync with server" button is more usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 has some offline capabilities. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline

But do you really have a business case for this? It will get complicated when you need to try and update stale data etc.

Comment: Yes, there is situation when i need to do this. I don't want to implement it in all the site but there a part of application, where i wanted to give this facility.

Comment: @amitmundra it can be tricky if you have to keep client-side track of changes, moreover you have to keep local copy of queried data too...it's all but not a small task and it may force you to rewrite/rethink all the client side part design + it'll add a big complexity on server side too (for example to manage conflicts).

Comment: @Adriano I was 50/50 but looks like coder had the same idea as me.

Comment: @Adriano: Yes you are right there may be duplicacy of data, and that might be increase traffic if data is large to be update from client to server. Is there any thing more that you can provide me for this?

Comment: @amitmundra about possible issues or about possible design?

Answer (score 0):

This requires use of JavaScript to store local data http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Working-with-HTML5-local-b0cbe2ef and it needs to check whether the server can be reached before doing a proper postback, or more likely just use AJAX to communicate between the JavaScript application and the server.

There are several applications like this such as Google Mail, and such solutions are more JavaScript based than ASP.NET and you need to avoid relying on the web forms mechanisms and use .NET for building the initial page, dealing with AJAX requests and managing the application data and persistence. See [How to write an offline version of an AJAX/ASP.NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507367/how-to-write-an-offline-version-of-an-ajax-asp-net-web-application)